# Make my clock animation fire one second/minute early

Tags: javascript, html, css, time

I'm trying to get my minute number and hour number animation fire one second early. As you will see, the animation currently occurs when the seconds roll off '00', I'd like the animation's to occur when the seconds roll off '59'.

I've tried altering the seconds to display one second faster to correct this useing.

```
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds + 1)
```

But the number goes crazy. I'm converting the timer numbers to background positions, which is probably lazy, but it seems a simple answer if I can get it to work properly. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Working demo can be found here. [Clock](http://infinitedv.co.uk/clock/)

```js
<script>
setInterval(function() {
 var date = new Date();
 var hours = date.getHours() * 100;
 var minutes = date.getMinutes() * 100;
 var seconds = date.getSeconds() * 100;
 var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds() / 10;
/* var minutesNormal = date.getMinutes();*/
 var minCounter = 0;
 var hourCounter = 0;
 
 if (seconds === 0) {
  minCounter = milliseconds - 100;
 } else {
  minCounter = 0;
 }
 if (minutes === 0) {
  hourCounter = milliseconds - 100;
 } else {
  hourCounter = 0;
 }
 
 var compClock = document.getElementById("compareClock").innerHTML = "<p>" + hours / 100 + " " + minutes / 100 + " " + seconds / 100 + "</p>" 
/*  + "<p>Nomral Minute: " + minutesNormal + "  Altered Minute: " + minutes / 100*/;
 var hoursBar = document.getElementById("hours").style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + (hours + hourCounter) + "px";
 var minutesBar = document.getElementById("minutes").style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + (minutes + minCounter) + "px";
 var secondsBar = document.getElementById("seconds").style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + (seconds + milliseconds) + "px";
 
/* alert(secondsBar);*/ 
 }, 10);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#container {
 width: 960px;
 position:relative;
 margin:auto;
}
#containerCover {
 height:100px;
 width:300px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 background-image: url(images/clock_front.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#clock {
 position:absolute;
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 background:#616161;
}
#hours {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image: url(images/hours.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: left;
}
#minSecContainer {
 width:200px;
 float: right;
}
#minutes {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image: url(images/minutes.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: left;
}
#seconds {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image: url(images/seconds.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: right;
}
#testDiv {
 background-image: url(images/minutes.jpg);
 background-position: 0px 100px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
 <div id="testDiv"></div>
 <div id="compareClock"></div>
 <div id="containerCover"></div>
 <div id="clock">
  <div id="hours"></div>
        <div id="minSecContainer">
         <div id="minutes"></div>
         <div id="seconds"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your working example has -> `3577
(index):49 Uncaught ReferenceError: hourCOunter is not defined`

Comment: Oops, corrected, thank you

Comment: To get a second early, you could do something like -> `var triggerWhen = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000);` you could then check the triggerWhen instead.

Comment: Would I replace the Zero in my if statement with that Variable? Sorry, I'm still a bit new at this.

Comment: I think you could just replace -> `var date = new Date();` with `var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000);` in your code, I only did the triggerWhen, in case you wanted keep track of current date too.  But looking at your code I'm not sure you need it..

Comment: Just tried. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I just altered you snippet to work in Stack Exchange, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  this does what you want..

```js
(function () {
  var 
    d_compareclock = document.getElementById("compareClock"),
    d_hours = document.getElementById("hours"),
    d_minutesBar = document.getElementById("minutes"),
    d_secondsBar = document.getElementById("seconds");
  
    setInterval(function() {
      var 
        date = new Date(),
        hours = date.getHours() * 100,
        minutes = date.getMinutes() * 100,
        milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds() / 10,
        seconds = date.getSeconds() * 100;
  
      if (date.getSeconds() >= 59) {
        minutes += milliseconds;
        if (date.getMinutes() >= 59) 
          hours += milliseconds;
      }

      d_compareclock.innerHTML = "<p>" + hours / 100 + 
        " " + minutes / 100 + " " + seconds / 100 + "</p>" 
      d_hours.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + (hours) + "px";
      d_minutesBar.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + 
        (minutes) + "px";
      d_secondsBar.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " +
        (seconds + milliseconds) + "px";
 
    }, 10);  
})();
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#container {
 width: 960px;
 position:relative;
 margin:auto;
}
#containerCover {
 height:100px;
 width:300px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 background-image: url(http://infinitedv.co.uk/clock/images/clock_front.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#clock {
 position:absolute;
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 background:#616161;
}
#hours {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image: url(http://infinitedv.co.uk/clock/images/hours.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: left;
}
#minSecContainer {
 width:200px;
 float: right;
}
#minutes {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image: url(http://infinitedv.co.uk/clock/images/minutes.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: left;
}
#seconds {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-image: url(http://infinitedv.co.uk/clock/images/seconds.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 float: right;
}
#testDiv {
 background-image: url(http://infinitedv.co.uk/clock/images/minutes.jpg);
 background-position: 0px 100px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="compareClock"></div>
 <div id="containerCover"></div>
 <div id="clock">
  <div id="hours"></div>
        <div id="minSecContainer">
         <div id="minutes"></div>
         <div id="seconds"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I've explained myself very well. I want the minute animation to change when the second 59 pulls down, at the moment it changes with 00. I've updated the online version with your code. It still works the same as before. Thank you for trying though,

Comment: Ah, in that case you want to advance the time for the minutes, I'll do an update ..

Comment: Ok done, you might want to do the same for hours, but I'll leave that one for you.  :)

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much, I've been trying to wrap my head round this for hours. I'll look through it and work out what you did now, and do the same for hours as you suggest. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem, actually I just thought the modification for hours is pretty simple.. I think the mod I've done will do the hours.. Just have to wait 10 mins to find out.. :)

Comment: Actually, I just advanced the date object by 8 mins, and indeed does the trick.. :)